# Ubuntu kernel upgrade fails : 20.04LTS

Tags: grub2, upgrade, kernel, dpkg, 20.04

I have upgraded my OS from 18.04.04 to Ubuntu-20.04 LTS. I used `update-manager –d` to upgrade.

When I try to run my `docker-compose`, it gives an error :

> runtime: mlock of signal stack failed: 12
>
> runtime: increase the mlock
>
> limit (ulimit -l) or runtime: update your kernel to 5.3.15+, 5.4.2+,
>
> or 5.5+ fatal error: mlock failed

I tried to upgrade my kernel verion to `5.4.25`

I have downloaded following `.deb` files from [official repository](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline)

```
linux-headers-5.4.25-050425_5.4.25-050425.202003121333_all.deb
linux-headers-5.4.25-050425-generic_5.4.25-050425.202003121333_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.4.25-050425-generic_5.4.25-050425.202003121333_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.4.25-050425-generic_5.4.25-050425.202003121333_amd64.deb
```

Then

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

sudo update-grub
sudo update-grub2

sudo reboot
```

When I select `5.4.25` from boot menu :

```
Loading Linux 5.4.25-xxxxx-generic
error: /vmlinuz-5.2.25-xxxxx-generic has invalid signature
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error : you need to load the kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

How can I upgrade my kernel to `5.4.25`

Current : `5.4.0-26-generic`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all it was a poor idea to install a mainline 5.4 kernel.

Ubuntu 20.04 has the 5.4 kernel by design. You don't get any advantage by installing a 5.4 kernel from mainline. It is the same kernel as used in Ubuntu but without Ubuntu-specific patches.

But if you really want to use mainline kernels, you'll have to disable Secure Boot in BIOS. Mainline kernels are not signed.

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue.

Comment: Ubuntu version 5.4.0-26 is actually mainline 5.4.30, OP is downgrading the kernel. https://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html